# Definition of an algebra over a field

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, representation-theory

My professor defined an algebra over a field as a vector space over that field that is also a ring. He did not state however with regard to what operations is the algebra a ring so can I assume the addition in the algebra is the usual addition in the sense of the algebra as a vector space over the field?

Comment: You guessed absolutely rigth (and it should have been clarified). Beyond that, the multiplication in the ring is compatible with the multiplication of vectors by a scalar

Comment: Also see my answer to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/563413/what-is-the-relationship-between-vector-spaces-and-rings/4034679#4034679) question which might help you along the way.